# POWER BI Refresh data source from Excel where file name changes daily

Tags: excel, powerbi

I am building a report in Power BI of my company's daily figures. Those figures are published each morning in an excel file to our company server. I would change the scripts that build this file, but at the moment that's not an option.

However, that file name has the date in it each day, so the filename CHANGES every day.

Essentially I am trying to use an expression for the excel query to include the system date in the concatenated filename each morning.

Comment: I am assuming that you are using Power Query (M) to open the given Excel file using something like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt260859.aspx If so, have a look at the M code opening the file and adjust it to make use of the [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt253492.aspx) function. If you require more help then please post your existing M code.

Comment: I had not been. I was aware of the existence of Power Query but have not used it. I will look into that and see if it solves my issue.

Up to this point I had literally just used Excel File under Get Data

Comment: In that case I'd recommend you start here: http://www.thebiccountant.com/learning-resources/ I guess the following video contains all you need to resolve your problem (together with the links I posted above): https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DBI-B410#fbid=

Answer (score 2):

Power BI's Queries can start by reading a folder of files (Get Data / Folder).  It treats them as a table of data (one row per file).

You can then filter that table (e.g. Sort by Date modified, Keep Rows / Keep Top Rows / 1), before using the Combine Files button on the Content column - this will generate a function that will work against any file(s) allowed through your filters.